# SQL Insert Statement Hangs

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

Here is my code. I am not getting an error statement, but the data is not inserted into the table. I tried running the query in PHPMyAdmin and it worked fine. It is also not because of user privileges.

```
  if ($mysql->connect_errno) {
        echo("Connect failed: ". $mysql->connect_error);
        die();
    }
    echo "I am confused by this thing<br>";

    if(isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0)
    {
        echo "Trying to figure out the errors!!!!<br>";
        $fileName = $mysql->real_escape_string($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
        $tmpName  = $mysql->real_escape_string($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);
        $fileSize = intval($_FILES['userfile']['size']);
        $fileType = $mysql->real_escape_string($_FILES['userfile']['type']);
        echo $fileName."<br>";
        echo $tmpName."<br>";
        echo $fileSize."<br>";
        echo $fileType."<br>";
        //reads the file information
        $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
        $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
        $content = $mysql->real_escape_string(addslashes($content));
        fclose($fp);
        //this just adds slashes
```

This adds slashes

```
        if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        {
            $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
        }

        //This inserts into the databse
        $query = "INSERT INTO upload VALUES ('', '$fileName', '$fileType', $fileSize, '$content')";
```

**This is the line where the code messes up... It just hangs and never prints out the die message**

```
        $updateDB = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error);
```

It never prints out this line.

```
        echo "<br>File $fileName uploaded<br>";
    }
```

Comment: don't store the file content in the db (unless there is a real good reason to)

Comment: Is there a reason you're switching from `$mysql` to `$mysqli` in the line that fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are working with `$mysql` object on the top and abruptly, you triggered your query on `$mysqli` object.

Change

```
$updateDB = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error);
```

to

```
$updateDB = $mysql->query($query) or die($mysql->error);
```